# AWS Lambda getting 403 when calling API gateway route

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS Lambda function that calls an API Gateway endpoint. The API uses an API key. Both the function and the API are C#/.NET Core 3.1  The API has CORS enabled and the routes in the API work as expected. I can call this new route from Postman and it works fine.

The first time I publish the Lambda function, I can invoke it and it works successfully. However, every subsequent invocation results in a 403.

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong here?

This is the output I'm getting from the function invocation:

```
START RequestId: <redacted> Version: $LATEST
Execution started for function: <redacted> at 3/26/2021 4:37:03 AM
Input string is: {}
StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: keep-alive
  Date: Fri, 26 Mar 2021 04:37:03 GMT
  x-amzn-RequestId: <redacted>
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token
  x-amzn-ErrorType: ForbiddenException
  x-amz-apigw-id: <redacted>
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT
  X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
  Via: 1.1 <redacted>.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
  X-Amz-Cf-Pop: SYD1-C2
  X-Amz-Cf-Id: <redacted>
  Content-Type: application/json
  Content-Length: 23
}
Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).: HttpRequestException
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at AWSLambda1.Function.FunctionHandler(String input, ILambdaContext context) in <redacted>\Function.cs:line 40
   at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )


END RequestId: <redacted>
REPORT RequestId: <redacted>    Duration: 263.07 ms Billed Duration: 264 ms Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 87 MB
```

The code that calls the API:

```
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", _apiKey);

            var response = await _client.PostAsync(_apiRoute, new StringContent("{}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            Console.WriteLine(response);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code of lambda function which calls the API?

Comment: Sure...added it to the original question

Comment: Did you check the cloud watch logs of API gateway to see why requests was rejected at the API end? You also might want to use `try-catch` block around `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` to catch `HttpRequestException` and log the message of the exception to know the reason of rejection. Or instead of `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` you can use `if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)` and try to read the response contents in the `else` block.

Comment: How long does it take for failure to occur?  If it is 30 seconds the connection may be trying to connect to a proxy server.  The solution may be to set the request proxy to null

Comment: Are you calling this method every time? Your `DefaultRequestHeaders` collection is adding your `x-api-key` at every request if that's the case. This might also explain why it works on the first request but not after. Can you try to check if the header exists? If it doesn't add it, if it does don't add another one.